# jQuery: Passing function in object?

Tags: jquery, object, fancybox

I'm trying to style the content of an iframe loaded with fancybox. I need to attach a function to the onComplete event handler, but it doesn't seem to work.

Am i doing this wrong?

```
    $(".contact-page .contact-form-buttons .fancybox.iframe").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        onComplete: function() {
            console.log('completed')
        }
    });
```

I don't get anything in the console. I tried onStart also, but didn't work either.

** Update **
Since Yuriy just posted a comment with the solution, i'll post the answer here. I was using the old api event handler, the equivilent for Fancybox 2+ is `afterLoad` or `beforeShow`.

Comment: It looks correct based on what I see in the [blog](http://fancybox.net/blog).  The only difference I see is that they wrap the keywords in single quotes so it would be 'onComplete' and likewise for the others.

Comment: Liam, it is indeed in `$(document).ready()`. NuclearGhost, i tried wrapping onComplete in quotes but no difference.

Comment: which fancybox version you're using?

Comment: Is it just the console.log thats not working? You tried an alert instead?

Comment: Fancybox 2.0.4 with jQuery 1.7.1. I can't update jQuery because other plugins are dependent on that specific version.

Comment: Check for fancyBox2 API documentation here (Callbacks tab): http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Liam, no success with alert() either.

Comment: Yuriy, that's embarassing! I was looking at the wrong api page, sigh. Thanks, afterLoad() seems to work great!

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick glance at other event implementations for the same plugin, and there seems to be 2 ways of doing it:

```
...
'onComplete'        : function() {
  console.log('completed');
}
...
```

or

```
....
complete: function() {
  console.log('completed');
}
...
```

Comment: The correct event to use is afterLoad. I was looking at the old version's API.